# Android Google Login works only when device connected

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I have a android application with integrated google login which I followed from this tutorial:
`https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in`

Now I want to log in and generate token id which works fine when I debug the application from the Android Studio.

I have exported the application as a `Signed APK` and installed it on my phone but then I am not able to log in with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be related to google developer console's debug key and/or release key. Which one do you have? Debug key could not be enough to install from apk.

VERY IMPORTANT EDIT:

To use the apk's located in [your_app_folder]/app/build/outputs/apk should be a solution to your problem.

Comment: How can I tell which one do I have? My application is not published to Play Store yet.

Comment: Well, you registered your application to Google Developer Console, you must already give your package names and they generate a key for you to put inside your app. You should look at the [credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) page. Select your project and produce a release key. By the way I am not sure this is the solution but at least worth to give a shot.

Comment: Before producing the release key, you should try apks located in [your project folder]/app/build/outputs/apk/. I will edit my answer too.